# Show slides of a banner that relate to specific users in SharePoint 2010

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I work in finance, but was asked by my manager to create a web site for our team. I have almost no knowledge of HTML or Javascript, a little bit of SharePoint 2010. I managed to create most of the content, but one issue is killing me. I need to create a rotating banner or a tabbed content so that when different users log in they see different slides or tabs. For example, if Manager A logs in he is supposed to see slides or tabs with his clients and links to daily reports of these clients. When Manager B logs is he can see only his clients etc. Manager A does not see Manager B's clients and vice versa.

My best guess now is to create tabs for all clients of all managers, and then hide the tabs based on the current user, but I have no idea how to implement the hide-part. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

P.S. The code for a rotating banner that I have so far is here:

```
    <div class="pageTitle">
News &amp; Announcements
</div>
<div class="OuterLeft">
    <div class="InnerLeft1" style="width:292px; margin-right:15px; float:left;"><menu class="ms-SrvMenuUI">
    <ie:menuitem id="MSOMenu_Help" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/HelpIcon.gif" onmenuclick="MSOWebPartPage_SetNewWindowLocation(MenuWebPart.getAttribute('helpLink'), MenuWebPart.getAttribute('helpMode'))" text="Help" type="option" style="display:none">

    </ie:menuitem>
</menu></div>
    <div class="InnerLeft2" style="width:292px; float:left;"></div>
    <div class="InnerLeftBottom">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td id="MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5" valign="top" class="s4-wpcell-plain"><table class="s4-wpTopTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><div WebPartID="0a0ee8ca-3783-456b-a7b2-3cdaf55f5a25" HasPers="false" id="WebPartWPQ5" width="100%" class="ms-WPBody noindex" allowDelete="false" style="" >
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/RotatingBanner/css/slider3.css">
<script src="/RotatingBanner/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/RotatingBanner/js/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.fp-slides').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        timeout: 5000,
        delay: 0,
        speed: 400,
        next: '.fp-next',
        prev: '.fp-prev',
        pager: '.fp-pager',
        continuous: 0,
        sync: 1,
        pause: 1,
        pauseOnPagerHover: 1,
        cleartype: true,
        cleartypeNoBg: true
    });
 });

</script>

<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:Keywords msdt:dt="string"></mso:Keywords>
<mso:_Author msdt:dt="string"></mso:_Author>
<mso:wic_System_Copyright msdt:dt="string"></mso:wic_System_Copyright>
<mso:_Comments msdt:dt="string"></mso:_Comments>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
<title></title></head>

<body>



<!-- Featured Content Slider Started -->
<div class="fp-slider clearfix">
    <div class="fp-slides-container clearfix">
        <div style="overflow: hidden;" class="fp-slides">


<!-- Slide 2 Code Start -->
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: -610px; display: none; z-index: 5; opacity: 1;" class="fp-slides-items">
                <div class="fp-thumbnail">
                    <img src="/RotatingBanner/images/President's-Perspective_600x250.png" />
                        </div>
                <div class="fp-content-wrap">
                    <div class="fp-content">
                        <h3 class="fp-title"><a href="https://us-intranet.milliman.com/ceoblog/default.aspx" style="color:#fff;">Risk management: We are not alone</a> </h3>

<p>Discussions at a recent conference show that consulting firms like Milliman face a variety of similar risk-related issues.&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://us-intranet.milliman.com/ceoblog/default.aspx" style="color:#fff;">continue reading &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fp-prev-next-wrap clearfix">
                        <a class="fp-next" href="#fp-next"></a>
                        <a class="fp-prev" href="#fp-prev"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Slide 2 Code End -->


   <!-- Slide 1 Code Start -->
                    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: -610px; display: none; z-index: 5; opacity: 1;" class="fp-slides-items">
                        <div class="fp-thumbnail">
                            <img src="/RotatingBanner/images/connectlogo-01.png" />
                                </div>
                        <div class="fp-content-wrap">
                            <div class="fp-content">
                                <h3 class="fp-title"><a href="/Pages/MillimanConnect.aspx" style="color:#fff;">OneNote to rule them all</a> </h3>

                                <p>Deborah Wolf of the Knowledge Management team discusses the versatile OneNote note-taking tool and shows how Milliman practices are using it to better track and share information.&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/Pages/MillimanConnect.aspx" style="color:#fff;">continue reading &raquo;</a></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fp-prev-next-wrap clearfix">
                                <a class="fp-next" href="#fp-next"></a>
                                <a class="fp-prev" href="#fp-prev"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <!-- Slide 2 Code End -->



















<!-- Slide 4 Code Start -->
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 6; opacity: 1; width: 600px; height: 249px;" class="fp-slides-items">
                <div class="fp-thumbnail">
                    <img src="https://us-intranet.milliman.com/RotatingBanner/images/Insight.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="fp-content-wrap">
                    <div class="fp-content">
                        <h3 class="fp-title"><a href="http://us.milliman.com/insight/" style="color:#fff;">Insight: Telematics, microinsurance, longevity plans, and more</a> </h3>
                        <p>Read Milliman's latest thought leadership pieces on the updated Insight page.
 &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://us.milliman.com/insight/" style="color:#fff;">continue reading &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fp-prev-next-wrap clearfix">
                        <a class="fp-next" href="#fp-next"></a>
                        <a class="fp-prev" href="#fp-prev"></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Slide 4 Code End -->



<!-- Slide 4 Code Start -->
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 6; opacity: 1; width: 600px; height: 249px;" class="fp-slides-items">
                <div class="fp-thumbnail">
                    <img src="/RotatingBanner/images/MMI.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="fp-content-wrap">
                    <div class="fp-content">
                        <h3 class="fp-title"><a href="http://us.milliman.com/uploadedFiles/insight/Periodicals/mmi/2015-MMI.pdf" style="color:#fff;">
2015 Milliman Medical Index</a> </h3>
                        <p>Healthcare costs for the typical American family of four reached $24,671 in 2015.
 &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://us.milliman.com/uploadedFiles/insight/Periodicals/mmi/2015-MMI.pdf" style="color:#fff;">continue reading &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fp-prev-next-wrap clearfix">
                        <a class="fp-next" href="#fp-next"></a>
                        <a class="fp-prev" href="#fp-prev"></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Slide 4 Code End -->














        </div>

        <div class="fp-nav">
            <span class="fp-pager"></span></div>
        </div>

    <div style="clear: both;">
        <!-- Featured Content Slider End -->
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 0 10px;">
        <div style="position:relative;float:left;width:280px;">
            <a href="/Lists/News%20Article%20Archive">View News Article Archives &raquo;</a>
        </div>
        <div style="position:relative;float:right;width:280px;text-align:right;">
            <a href="mailto:newsbreak@milliman.com?subject=News%20Idea%20for%20Milliman%20Intranet%20and%20Newsbreak" >Submit a News Idea &raquo;</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br clear="all"/>
</body>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br clear="all"/>

</body>
</body>

</html>


</body>

</html>
/>

</body>
</body>

</html>


</body>

</html>
</div></td>
            </tr>
        </table><div class="ms-PartSpacingVertical"></div></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple way you can do this, this just snippet I'm giving

```
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
var currentUser;
function init(){
this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
}

 function onQuerySucceeded() {
if(currentUser.get_loginName() == "manager a")
 {
document.getElementById('managerA').style.display = 'block';
}
 else if(currentUser.get_loginName() == "manager b")
 {
 document.getElementById('managerB').style.display = 'block';
 }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>


 <div id="managerA" style="display:none">
 //manager A links and content
 </div>
 <div id="managerB" style="display:none">
 //manager B links and content
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you vinayak! I have a question, though. Where exactly should I place your code? Should I append it to the code I wrote above and add some content between <div id="manager A" ...</div> ? Or should I place parts of my code inside the divs?